# Why does the first user flair in a page dominate?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, internet-explorer

#### Or: Aaronut is six moderators *by himself*

Observe:

[image: image of six Aaronut flairs]

To reproduce this, visit https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/about. Now click on some link in the page; I chose the "parent" link at the top of the screen. Now click back.

If your browser is anything like mine (and let's hope it isn't, because I wouldn't wish IE7 on anyone), everyone has just moved up a slot -- Sam Holder is gone and Aaronut now occupies two spots. Do it enough times and you'll discover that Aaronut is singlehandedly keeping the cooking trolls at bay.

I also reproduced this on the main [SO about page](https://stackoverflow.com/about), only there it works a bit differently. After clicking somewhere and then going back, each of the left column occupies the corresponding slot on the right column also.

[image: image of Marc Gravell, Gumbo, and Will bravely holding down the fort]

So, um, that's not supposed to happen, is it?

Comment: mmyers what browser are you using, I've tried it in a few different browsers and can't duplicate

Comment: IE7. @xiaohouzi79

Comment: Your browser sucks... ;)

Comment: No repro in WinXP + FF 3.6.6.

Comment: No repro in Opera.

Comment: No repro in IE8 or Chrome 6.0.472.62 - win xp.

Comment: __No repro with IE7__ on XP SP3. I tried returning to the page by using a link and by using the back button. I tried while logged in and while logged out. All flairs appeared correctly in every case. (That said, @Aaro _is_ a force to be reckoned with.)

Comment: Hmm. I'm on Vista, but I wouldn't have thought the OS would make a difference. @Pop

Comment: @mmyers, I didn't even know you _could_ have IE7 on Vista. Thought it shipped with IE8. But that's neither here nor there. Let me know if you want me to do additional testing of some sort.

Comment: @Popular Demand Vista shipped with IE7, Win7 shipped with IE8.

Comment: @Brian, d'oh! Thanks for the correction.

Comment: No not on my XP SP3 IE7

Comment: @Benny: Are you saying you *can* or *can't* reproduce the bug? It was marked completed, but I no longer have to use IE7 (or even have access to it) so I don't have first-hand knowledge.

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer an issue with the new image flair.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Confirmed in IE7

Comment: What operating system?